# How to delete an object where it consist with multiple objects in ORM-Lite

Tags: android, orm, ormlite

I am using ORM-lite for an Android application, Model class is as follows,

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "pageimage")
public class PageImage
{

@DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
private int pageimageId;
@DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, uniqueCombo=true)
private Page page;
@DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, uniqueCombo=true)
private Image image;
@DatabaseField
private int order;


//implementation

}
```

PageImage object is created with combination of Page and Image objects referenced to Page and Image tables. i have searched a lot but still unable to find a away to delete a PageImage object where Page id  = "some value" and Image id = "some value" .

Appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DeleteBuilder](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/DeleteBuilder.html) to do that.

```
    private void deletePageItem(Page page, Image image) {
    try {
        Dao<PageItem, ?> dao = mOpenHelper.getDao(PageItem.class);
        DeleteBuilder<PageItem, ?> deleteBuilder = dao.deleteBuilder();
        deleteBuilder.where().eq(PageItem.COLUMN_IMAGE, image).and().eq(PageItem.COLUMN_PAGE, page);
        deleteBuilder.delete();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

where `mOpenHelper` is entity extended from [OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-android/com/j256/ormlite/android/apptools/OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.html)

PageItem.java

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "pageimage")
public class PageItem {

    public static final String COLUMN_PAGE = "page";
    public static final String COLUMN_IMAGE = "image";

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int pageimageId;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = COLUMN_PAGE, foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, uniqueCombo = true)
    private Page page;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = COLUMN_IMAGE, foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, uniqueCombo = true)
    private Image image;
    @DatabaseField
    private int order;


}
```

Comment: Hi Gio, i found it, thank you very much for your time and effort. really appreciate

Comment: Hi G_V, nothing specific, same as Gio's solution:)